# How to find all .jpg, .png and .gif and list them into a grid with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, bookmarklet

I would like to build a basic [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) that finds all .jpg, .png and .gif images of a web page and list them into a grid. (e.g. 4 images in a row)
I just found this snippet but it pushes all image no matter of the extension:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
var srcList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    srcList.push(images[i].src);
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: You need to filter them.

Comment: Just use a regex on the `src` attribute, and then push conditionally

Comment: `var images = document.querySelectorAll('[src$=".jpg"], [src$=".png"], [src$=".gif"]')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) and use a regular expression to get the images with the extensions:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[src$=".jpg"], img[src$=".png"], img[src$=".gif"]');
var srcList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    srcList.push(images[i].src);
}
```

To generate a list of images you could do:

```
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = images[i].src;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

You have to add some CSS to make it a grid.

Comment: Thanks for your example! Do you have also an idea on how to generate a HTML grid with the srcList image paths? (So you can see them all)

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to filter the array

```
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var srcList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var im = images[i];
        var src = im.src;
        var ext = src.substring(lastIndexOf('.'));
        if (ext == '.jpg' || ext == '.png' || ext == '.gif') {
            srcList.push(images[i].src);
        }
    }
```

By the way, using querySelectedAll is far more elegant solution as mentioned in comments..